# Getting volley response is null on first call

Tags: android, android-volley

This my class for network calls. Here executing a method networkCallByVolley then saving the information on shared preferences.

```
 public class NetworkCall extends Activity {
        Context context;
        String res = "something";

        SharedPreferences userDetails;


         ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();
         ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();


    public NetworkCall(Context context){
        this.context = context;


    }

        public void networkCallByVolley(final ArrayList<String> type, final ArrayList<String> value){

            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
            Log.i("type", type.toString());
            Log.i("value", value.toString());



            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                    "http://My URL",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {




                            Log.i("rrrrr", response);

                            res = response;

                             userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
                            edit.clear();
                            edit.putString("response", response);

                            edit.commit();

                            //Log.i("rrrrr", response);



                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                        }
                    }) {
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  //for(int i = 0; i<= params1.size(); i++)

                    for(int i =0 ; i< type.size(); i++){
                    params.put(type.get(i), value.get(i));
                    //params.put("password", "aaaaaa");
                   Log.i("typpppp", type.get(i));
                    }


                    return params;
                };
            };

            queue.add(myReq);

           }
         public String getCharlie(){
             userDetails = context.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
             return userDetails.getString("response", "no value found");
         }
        public void clearCharlie(){
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.commit();
        }

        }
```

when i am trying to use this class from login activity i am getting  message for the below log  "pref response" is "no value found". if run it again i am getting proper response which i am expecting. I don't know how to fix this bug. any help is appreciated.
this is my main activity

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    Button signup,submit;
    EditText email,password;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login);


final  NetworkCall net = new NetworkCall(getApplicationContext());

    final ArrayList<String> type = new ArrayList<String>();



    final ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();


    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_pwd);

    type.add("user_email");
    type.add("user_password");

    value.add(email.getText().toString().trim());
    value.add(password.getText().toString().trim());


    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         net.networkCallByVolley(type, value);
         String response = net.getCharlie();



    Log.i("pref resonse", response);

        }
    });




}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ASYNC task or handler. 
What you are doing is calling getCharlie() method right after you made the call net.networkCallByVolley(type, value); It takes some time to get response from the sever after which only it will write the response to the shared prefrences. You are getting no result found because at that time there is no response. Respone is being calculated on some another parallel thread. As soon as that thread gets the response it show that to you but until then you will be having null. So wait for the thread to get response using ASYNC task.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         net.networkCallByVolley(type, value); 
         String response = net.getCharlie(); 
         while(response.equalsIgnorecase("no result found")){} 
         Log.i("pref resonse", response);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks. it does make sense. Is there is any other way we can do from the above code with out using the async task to achieve the result.

Comment: use while loop
 net.networkCallByVolley(type, value);
         String response = net.getCharlie(); while(response.equalsIgnorecase("no result found){} 
Log.i("pref resonse", response);

Comment: I didn't get it . Where i have to use while loop ??

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to wait until getting response from Volley.
You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Login Activity`
and send a broadcast from `NetworkCall Activity` after you get a response from the server, and when you receive a broadcast do what you want to do e.g checking `SharedPreferences`.

Alternative way you can use is Observer Pattern to get notice when you get response from server.